# Smooth scroll JS working with jQuery 1.11.1, but break with jQuery 1.12.3

Tags: javascript, jquery

This JS creates a Smooth scroll, it works with jQuery 1.11.1, but break with jQuery 1.12.3. Using this with a Wordpress site and would prefer not to load two versions of jQuery.

Can't figure out what to update to make it work again.

```
    <!--smooth scroll to anchors-->
    <script>
    (function($){
      var jump=function(e){
        if (e){
          e.preventDefault();                   //prevent the "normal" behavior which would be a "hard" jump
          var mytarget = $(this).attr("href");  //get the target
        }else{
          var mytarget = location.hash;             //sets the target to the anchor part of a URL
        }

      $('html,body').animate(                           //perform animated scrolling
      {
        scrollTop: $(mytarget).offset().top - 100   //get top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target and move down 100px for fixed nav
        }, 1000,function(){                         //scrolldelay: 2 seconds
        location.hash = mytarget;                   //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
        });
      }

      $('html, body').hide()

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

        if (location.hash){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
            jump()
          }, 0);
        }else{
          $('html, body').show()
        }
      });
    })(jQuery)
    </script>
    <!--End smooth scroll-->
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 1.12.x does not like `a[href^=#]` without quotes around #.

It throws an unrecognized expression error.

Using quotes is recommended always.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').bind("click", jump);
```

Also there's an issue with your scrolltop in all jquery versions. $(..).offset() is null. This happens when your href is `#` or links to a non-existing id. You should also check that it's not an external link, and return, otherwise preventDefault will stop it from working.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/txau5yLf/

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.